# How to combine two lists in one list? using notepad++ regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of textfile such as below example:

```
username1
username2
username3
```

I want a regex that can make it like following example:

```
username1:username1
username2:username2
username3:username3
```

etc..

I've tried many regex with failed attempts.

Comment: What is the rule here? Just duplicate the whole line after a `:`?

Comment: Just replace `.+` with `$0:$0` - my guess is you haven't tried hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just click Ctrl + H to open the replace window, and follow the attached picture.

[image]